# How Do I Reselect A KendoUI TabStrip After AJAX Postback in UpdatePanel

Tags: kendo-ui, updatepanel

**Setup**
I've got a Telerik Kendo UI TabStrip with multiple tabs inside of an UpdatePanel...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="DataDetails_Panel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<div id="ABIOptions_TabContainer">
     <ul>
         <li>Attendance</li>
         <li>Grades</li>
         <li>Gradebook</li>
         <li>PFT</li>
         <li>Scheduling</li>
         <li>Miscellaneous</li>
         <li>Parent Data Changing</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

...which I then wire up in javascript later...

```
var optionTabContainer = $("#ABIOptions_TabContainer").kendoTabStrip({
     animation: {
         open: {
             effects: "fadeIn"
         }
     },
     select: onMainTabSelect
}).data("kendoTabStrip");
```

**Scenario**
The users will click on the various tabs and inside of each tab are settings for our portal.  When they are in a tab and they make a change to a setting, the expectation is that they'll click on the 'Save' button, which will perform a postback to the server via ajax, because it is in the update panel.

**Current Behavior**
After the post back happens and the `ul` content comes back, I reapply the kendoTabStrip setup function call, which makes none of the tabs selected.  This appears to the user like the page is now empty, when it just had content.

**Desired Result**
What I want to do, is after the partial postback happens and the UpdatePanel sends back the  `ul`, I want to reselect the tab that the user previously selected.

**What Already Works**
I already have a way to preserve the tab that the user clicked on:

```
var onMainTabSelect = function (e) {
        tabToSelect = e.item;
        console.log("onTabSelect --> ", e.item.textContent);
}
```

and a function to reset the selected tab whenever it is called:

```
function setMainTab() {
    if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(tabToSelect)) {
        var tabStrip = $('#ABIOptions_TabContainer').data("kendoTabStrip");
        console.log("Attempt to set tab to ", tabToSelect.textContent);
        tabStrip.select(tabToSelect);
    } else {
        console.log("tabToSelect was empty");
    }
}
```

**What Doesn't Work**
My hypothesis is that the Kendo TabStrip says, "Hey, that tab is already selected" when I call the `setMainTab` after my postback:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    BindControlEvents();
    setMainTab();
});
```

...and therefore, doesn't set my tab back.  If I click on the tab, then Poof, all my content is there just like I expect.

**Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the `onMainTabSelect` method to:

```
var onMainTabSelect = function (e) {
   tabToSelect = $(e.item).data("tabindex");
}
```

which gets me the data-tabindex value for each `li` in my `ul`.  I couldn't get the tab index from kendo, so I had to role my own.  Once I got that value, then I was able to set the selected tab via an index rather than the tab object reference itself.